# c# XmlSerializer deserializer missing default namespace

Tags: c#, xmlserializer

Below is an example payload response from an integration I am currently working on.  The response does not set a default namespace (xml2 variable in example) and the issue is that XmlSerializer does not assume the default namespace is "d".  I have tried setting the default namespace in the XMLSerializer constructor but that doesn't work either.   As well, I can't expect the "service" to update/fix their side.  Is there some other settings I can pass that will correctly populate the class?

Thanks,
Chuck

```
using System;
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Serialization;
using System.IO;

namespace TestXmlNamespace
{
    [XmlRoot(ElementName = "root", Namespace = "my_test_ns1")]
    public class Test
    {
        public string name { get; set; }
        public int age { get; set; }

        [XmlElement(Namespace = "my_test_ns2")]
        public int ageInMonths { get; set; }

        public override bool Equals(object obj)
        {
            return obj is Test b && name == b.name && age == b.age && ageInMonths == b.ageInMonths;
        }

        public void Run(string str, string name)
        {
            XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Test));
            using (StringReader rStream = new StringReader(str))
            {
                Test test = serializer.Deserialize(rStream) as Test;
                Console.Out.WriteLine(test.Equals(this) ? $"{name} equals expected" : $"{name} does not equal expected");
            }
        }
    }

    class Program
    {
        const string xml1 = @"<?xml version=""1.0"" encoding=""UTF-8"" ?>
<d:root xmlns:d=""my_test_ns1"" xmlns:v=""my_test_ns2"">
  <d:name>Bill</d:name>
  <d:age>32</d:age>
  <v:ageInMonths>384</v:ageInMonths>
</d:root>
";

        const string xml2 = @"<?xml version=""1.0"" encoding=""UTF-8"" ?>
<d:root xmlns:d=""my_test_ns1"" xmlns:v=""my_test_ns2"">
  <name>Bill</name>
  <age>32</age>
  <v:ageInMonths>384</v:ageInMonths>
</d:root>
";

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Test expected = new Test()
            {
                name = "Bill",
                age = 32,
                ageInMonths = 384
            };

            expected.Run(xml1, "xml1");
            expected.Run(xml2, "xml2");
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution and I am posting it for those in the future who may run across this problem and hopefully I will help them save some time.

Simply put, when an element does not have a namespace prefix XmlSerializer treats it has not part of a name space so specifying an empty name space in the element attribute handles this.  See the updated example code below.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Serialization;
using System.IO;

namespace TestXmlNamespace
{
    public class CustomXmlTextReader : XmlTextReader
    {
        private readonly string DefaultNamespace = String.Empty;

        public CustomXmlTextReader(StringReader reader, string defaultNamespace) : base(reader)
        {
            DefaultNamespace = defaultNamespace;
        }

        public override string NamespaceURI => String.IsNullOrEmpty(base.NamespaceURI) ? DefaultNamespace : base.NamespaceURI;
    };

    [XmlRoot(ElementName = "root", Namespace = "my_test_ns1")]
    public class Test
    {
        [XmlElement("name", Namespace = "")] // Set namespace to empty string when no namespace prefix specified in xml
        public string name { get; set; }

        [XmlElement("age", Namespace = "")] // Set namespace to empty string when no namespace prefix specified in xml
        public int age { get; set; }

        [XmlElement(Namespace = "my_test_ns2")]
        public int ageInMonths { get; set; }

        public override bool Equals(object obj)
        {
            return obj is Test b && name == b.name && age == b.age && ageInMonths == b.ageInMonths;
        }

        public void Run(string str, string name)
        {
            using (StringReader rStream = new StringReader(str))
            {
                //using (XmlTextReader tr = new CustomXmlTextReader(rStream, "my_test_ns1"))
                using (XmlTextReader tr = new XmlTextReader(rStream))
                {
                    XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Test));
                    Test test = serializer.Deserialize(tr) as Test;
                    Console.Out.WriteLine(test.Equals(this) ? $"{name} equals expected" : $"{name} does not equal expected");
                }
            }
        }
    }

    class Program
    {
        const string xml = @"<?xml version=""1.0"" encoding=""UTF-8"" ?>
<d:root xmlns:d=""my_test_ns1"" xmlns:v=""my_test_ns2"">
  <name>Bill</name>
  <age>32</age>
  <v:ageInMonths>384</v:ageInMonths>
</d:root>
";

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Test expected = new Test()
            {
                name = "Bill",
                age = 32,
                ageInMonths = 384
            };

            expected.Run(xml, "xml1");
        }
    }
}
```